# Can I change the format of a list number in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, numbering

I have a numbered list such as this:

1. Item 1
2. **Item 2**
3. Item 3

I would like to typeset the "2." in bold as well. Is this possible in Word 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look carefully, you can see an additional "fake space" at the end of every line of the numbered list. This space is only visible if you highlight it by dragging the mouse over it. For example, the actual characters in your text are the following (except the quotes):

`"1. blah"`
`"2. foo"`
`"3. fun"`

But if you drag the mouse in the space just behind the last character on the line, you will see a space, represented by the `_` character here:

`"1. blah_"`
`"2. foo_"`
`"3. fun_"`

Drag over that space and select Bold or any other formatting and it should only apply to the number **on the same line as the space**. Note that you can't "reach" this character by pressing the left and right arrow keys on the keyboard, but that the answer by Creator is another way of getting to it (but his way makes you bold the entire line; with my solution, you can bold **only** the number).

**Important additional info from the OP**:

> Note to future readers, the 'spaces' are unprintable marks that can be displayed/hidden with CTRL+* or by clicking the ¶ button. So this solution is essentially, "format the paragraph ending break in bold" which usually has no direct effect but in lists has the side effect of formatting the list number in bold

Comment: Thanks. Note to future readers, the 'spaces' are unprintable marks that can be displayed/hidden with CTRL+* or by clicking the ¶ button. So this solution is essentially, "format the paragraph ending break in bold" which usually has no direct effect but in lists has the side effect of formatting the list number in bold.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, just put the cursor anywhere in the item 2 and follow these keys.

```
End > Shift+Home > Ctrl+b
```

It'll make the complete line with the bullet no. bold.